# Post an array of complex objects with JSON, MVC model is do not bind

Tags: arrays, json, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

here is my codes.

json_model

```
var mix = {
        MixName: $("#mixname").val(),
        MixDesc: tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent(),
        Price: $("#price").val(),
        DiseaseMixs: [],
        MixProducts: []
    }
```

Add items to DiseaseMixs and MixProducts

```
$("#DiseaseList").find("tbody tr").each(function (index) {
        mix.DiseaseMixs.push({
            MixID: parseInt(MixID),
            DiseaseID: parseInt($(".diseaseid").eq(index).html()),
            ImpactDegree: parseInt($(".derece option:selected").eq(index).html()),
            Description: $(".diseaseMixDesc input").eq(index).val()
        });
    })
    $("#productList").find("tbody tr").each(function (index) {
        mix.MixProducts.push({
            MixID: parseInt(MixID),
            ProductID: parseInt($(".productid").eq(index).html()),
            MeasureTypeID: parseInt($(".birim option:selected").eq(index).val()),
            MeasureAmount: $(".measureAmount input").eq(index).val()
        });
    })
```

and end of this process, here is a sample json object that is post.

```
{
"MixName": "asdasddas",
"MixDesc": "<p>sadasd</p>",
"Price": "123",
"DiseaseMixs": [{
    "MixID": 1,
    "DiseaseID": 2,
    "ImpactDegree": 5,
    "Description": "asads"
}, {
    "MixID": 1,
    "DiseaseID": 3,
    "ImpactDegree": 4,
    "Description": "aqqq"
}],
"MixProducts": [{
    "MixID": 1,
    "ProductID": 2,
    "MeasureTypeID": 3,
    "MeasureAmount": "3"
}, {
    "MixID": 1,
    "ProductID": 3,
    "MeasureTypeID": 2,
    "MeasureAmount": "45"
}]
}
```

ajax post

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'SaveMix',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(mix),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status) {
            alert(status);
            console.log(xhr);
        }


    })
```

and MVC Model and JSONResult function

Model

```
public class MixModel
{
    public string MixName { get; set; }
    public string MixDesc { get; set; }
    public float Price { get; set; }
    DiseaseMix[] DiseaseMixs { get; set; } //DiseaseMix EntityFramework entity
    MixProduct[] MixProducts { get; set; } //MixProduct EF

}
```

function

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SaveMix(MixModel mix)
    {
        bool result = false;
        //do something

        return Json(new { result = result }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and here is the result I get is.

[image]

No matter how I tried, I could not bind the model.

What am I doing wrong? Please give me some help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model binding is failing because those 2 properties are currently `private`(which is the default when you don't specify anything explicitly).

Change the 2 properties to `public` so that model binder can set the values of those.

```
public class MixModel
{
    public string MixName { get; set; }
    public string MixDesc { get; set; }
    public float Price { get; set; }
    public DiseaseMix[] DiseaseMixs { get; set; } //DiseaseMix EntityFramework entity
    public MixProduct[] MixProducts { get; set; } //MixProduct EF

}
```

*I also suggests to not mix your view models with entities generated by your ORM. That creates a tightly coupled solution.*